# Is it possible to simultaneously acquire 2 values from the Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, visualstudio

I am currently making a project using a resistive touch screen and an Arduino Uno. The resistive touch screen outputs an X and Y coordinate pair, which I then want to be able to read and output on an X-Y scatter plot in Visual Basic. I am wondering if it's possible to collect these X and Y coordinates at the same time, and read them through the serial port so they can be used in Visual Basic.

Comment: no you cannot collect the X and Y coordinates simultaneously ..... those two values would be collected one after the other, some microseconds apart

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Arduino forum I will answer the Arduino part of your question. Yes you can get the coordinates and get them into the computer via a serial port.